# how to make livewire v3 understand event when checkbox is clicked

Tags: laravel

```
<div>
    @foreach ($data as $index => $row)
        <tr wire:key="row-{{ $index }}">
            <td>
                <div class="form-check form-switch form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="rollup" wire:click="toggleRollup"
                        {{ $row->roll_up == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

When I click on the checkbox it doesn't send any events or run the toggleRollup() function.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue60W.png)

I want when I click on the checkbox it will show "hi" in the toggleRollup function